Cannot run Apache Tomcat on AWS FSx as a Windows service
I have a AWS FSx server in the same VPC as my EC2's, and has a Directory Service. I am able to connect to with my Admin user from the same domain to the EC2 and the FSx server (mapped as Z:).
Running the startup.bat as a user on the FSx works, but the problem occurs when I configure this as a Windows Service using service.bat and trying to run it.
I gave the Windows Service the Admin login, but it gave me the error: Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Also creating a new local user account (ServiceRunner) and adding this to the Directory Service with the same credentials, and making my Windows Service use this as login does not change anything.
Next I have tried to use a batch script to map the drive on startups so that the user has knowledge of the Z: drive.
@echo off
net use Z: "\\path\to\folder" "/USER:domain\Admin" "password" "/PERSISTENT:YES"
Z:
cd Z:\apache-tomcat\bin
startup.bat

I used NSSM to configure this batch script as a Windows Service, but running this gives the following error:
Windows could not start the service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.
After this I logged in with ServiceRunner and executed the commands from the batch script manually, and everything works.
PS: The same tomcat worked on the C:/ drive. The tomcat on Z:/ is a copy.
What can I do to make this work as a Windows service?
